# Something is wrong or missing with my code

Tags: php

I am trying to see if each product is available or not. Instead I get all the products sold or avalilable.
Need some advice

```
<td>                    
    <?php
    $itQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE deleted = 0");
    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itQuery);    
    $item = array();
    $sizes = sizesToArray($product['sizes']);
        foreach($sizes as $size){
            if($size['quantity'] <= $size['threshold']){
            $item = array(
            'quantity' => $size['quantity'],
            'threshold' => $size['threshold'],
            );
        }
    }
?>
<?=($item['quantity'] == 0)? ' Sold' : ' Available';?>
</td>
```

Comment: I think we need some more information about what you actually want and the output you expect to see. However, your SQL query `SELECTs` all of your (non-deleted) products so perhaps that needs to be refined.

Comment: Actually I get the information I want, but it affects the rest of the products too

Answer (score 2):

The problems:

1. The `$item` is an array and it doesn't have `quantity` index.
2. You have to set up `$item["quantity"]` and put it inside the loop.

The best solution is to move this line inside the loop:

```
<?= ($size['quantity'] == 0)? ' Sold' : ' Available';?>
```

Comment: I am not quite sure that I understand your solution

Comment: @Harry Remove this line: `<?=($item['quantity'] == 0)? ' Sold' : ' Available';?>` and put the given line after `'threshold' => $size['threshold'],
                            );`.

Comment: @Harry How the hell you can't understand a simple but detailed solution with explanation given by Praveen Kumar? Are you just copying codes instead of studying it?